# refresh data in dataTable when column is reordered in javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vue.js, datatable

I have a dataTable component in my Vuejs application, that I use to display tables.
It has a 'data' prop value that allows it to take the data to show in the table.
here is how I call the component:

```
<aDataTable :data="sites">
        <template #columns> <!-- showing columns here --> </template >
        <template #rows> <!-- showing rows here --> </template >
<aDataTable>
```

I would like to be able to refresh the data when one of the column headers is clicked.
I would like the sorting to be done on the server-side, hence why im doing it this way.
This is kind of what I would like to do but not sure how

```
$('#data-table').on('order.dt', function () { 
       // gets the value of the header of the column and using to sort the data in the table
}
```

Any idea how one can do this?

Comment: What is aDataTable ? If you're using third-party component, the question should explain this. This is specific to how it's implemented

Comment: yes, I am using this: https://datatables.net/examples/index

Comment: I've found jquery doesn't play well with some of the other children in the framework sand lot. I always say, if you're using jquery in a vuejs application, you're doing it wrong - do any of those examples suggest how to use dataTable with vuejs?

Comment: I found something that may help you using jquery/datatables with vuejs on the datatables forum https://datatables.net/q/?q=vuejs